# Asker offers to add more code if asked in comments

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I spotted today the following question:

[View is getting replaced while Scrolling in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258956/view-is-getting-replaced-while-scrolling-in-uitableview)

There was the following statement:

> If you need any code snippets from any part of the App, please comment below.

On one side it's redundant and doesn't add anything of value to the topic, so it should be removed.

On the other hand, it's saying that the asker doesn't know what to post, but knows that some code should be posted (also - less importantly - suggests that they are ready to provide more details). Removing it can attract more downvotes and VTCs, to a question that the OP has put some effort into.

**Should I remove this statement?**

Answer (score -3):

If they have all the code that they need, then it's just fluff and should be removed. On the other hand, if they *don't*, then it's a good notice to close voters to exercise patience with this user.

Closure for lack of code or clarity sends a powerful message to askers: nobody's going to answer their question, nobody's *allowed* to answer their question, until it gets *fixed*. I've always thought that this was the point of those close reasons, as there are some people who think that their questions are "good enough" as-is, and that they don't need to fix them because someone will answer them no matter how ambiguous and lacking they are.

On the other hand, this asker has expressed a vested interest in making sure that potential answerers have all information that they need—they're just not sure what they'll need. Thus, the "powerful message" becomes redundant so a reviewer outside the CVQ should add a comment directing them to add the code, and wait around 24 hours *before* resorting to a close vote, since reopening a question can take a long time.

Comment: "*I've always thought that this was the point of those close reasons*" No, the principle purpose of closure for *any* close reason is to prevent people from answering a question when those answers would be guesses at what the real problem is, would be subjective posts that we don't want, or would be off-topic for what we want on the site.

Comment: _"nobody's_ allowed _to answer their question, until it gets_ fixed" If only that were true ;-(

Comment: @ThomasSchremser That is true when there are 5 close voters. [Ignoring some weird design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928).